# Extension of a linear transformation and Zorn's lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Let $V,W$ be vector spaces over some field $\mathbb{F}$ and $B$ a subspace of $V$ and $T:B \longrightarrow W$ a linear transformation.Then $T$ can be extended to a linear transformation $L$ on $V$,i.e there is a linear transformation $L:V \longrightarrow W$ such that $L|_B=T$.

This is an exercise from Derek Goldray's book, Classical set theory.

I would like to show my attempt to prove this:

$Proof:$

Let $A$ be the family of pairs $(S,L)$ where $S \supseteq B$ and $S$ is a linear subspace of $V$ and $L:S \longrightarrow W$ a linear transformation such that $L|_B=T$

We now partially order $A$ in this way: $(S_1,L_1) \leqslant (S_2,L_2) \Longleftrightarrow S_1 \subseteq S_2$ and $L_2|_{S_1}=L_1$

We have that $A \neq \emptyset$ because $(B,T) \in A$.

Let $C=\{(S_i,L_i)|i \in I\}$ be a chain in $A$ and let $(M,F)$ be the pair where $M=\bigcup_{i \in I}S_i$ and $F:M \longrightarrow W$ such that $F(x)=L_i(x),x \in S_i$.

We can easily see that $M$ is a linear subspace of $V$ using the fact that any two elements in a chain are comparable.

Also let $x,y \in M$. So $x \in S_i$ and $y \in S_j$ for some $i,j \in I$.But $S_i \subseteq S_j$ or $S_j \subseteq S_i$.

Assume that $S_j \subseteq S_i$. We know that $S_i$ is a subspace of $V$ thus $x,y \in S_i \Longrightarrow x+y \in S_i$ and $F(x+y)=L_i(x+y)=L_i(x)+L_i(y)=F(x)+F(y)$.

In the same way we can prove that $F(ax)=aF(x),\forall x \in M,\forall a \in \mathbb{F}$. Thus $F$ is a linear transformation and an extension of $T$.

Clearly $(M,F)$ is an upperbound of $C$ because $\forall (S_i,L_i) \in C$ we have that $S_i \subseteq M$ and $F|_{S_i}=L_i \Longrightarrow (S_i,L_i) \leqslant (M,F), \forall i \in I$ and $(M,F)\in C$ ,thus form Zorn's lemma exists a maximal element $(S_0,L_0) \in A$

Now we need to show that $S_0=V$.

Let $S_0 \subsetneq V$ and $z \in V$ \ $S_0$.

Let $Y=<S_0,z>=\{s+az|s \in S_0,a \in \mathbb{F}\}$.Clearly $S_0 \subsetneq Y$ and $Y$ is a proper  subspace of $V$.

Let $L_1: Y \longrightarrow W$ such that $L_1(s+az)=L_0(s)+av$ for some $v \in W$

$L_1$ is a linear transformation.

$$L_1(s)=L_1(s+0z)=L_0(s)$$ $$L_1(z)=L_1(\bar{0}+1z)=L_0(\bar{0})+v=\bar{0}+v=v$$

We have that $L_1(S_0)=L_0(S_0)$ \Longrightarrow $(S_0,L_0)<(Y,L_1)$

This is a contradiction because of the maximality of $(S_0,L_0)$ thus $$S_0=V$$

Is my attempt correct?

Thnak you in advance!

Comment: i don't see any error

Comment: Seems ok to me. Nice proof.

Comment: I want to be sure if i took the right  linear transformation to contradict the maximality of the element $(S_0,L_0)$

Comment: I used most of the ideas from the use of zorn's lemma in the proof of hahn-banach's theorem except the second part  where i contradicted the maximality of the maximal element..The second part concerns me more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a problem, but is easy to fix. You can't define $L_1 : Y \rightarrow W$ as $ L_1(s + az) = L_0 (s) + a z$ because you don't know if $z$ $\in$ $W$ ($W$ and $V$ may be diferent vector spaces) an easy way to solve this is defining $ L_1(s + az) = L_0 (s) + a v$, for some $v$ $\in$ $W$.

Comment: yes you are right..i edited  it ..thank you!

Comment: Does a similar proof work in the case when $T$ is a bounded linear map, and we are looking for an extension that's bounded as well? I can't seem to mimic the analogous steps in the Hahn-Banach Theorem.

Comment: @user82261 note that when you find the upper bound of the chain $C$. The pair $(M, F)$ (using his notation) may not be a bounded linear map.

Answer (score 2):

You have essentially proved [Baer's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module#Baer.27s_criterion) for fields.

A different strategy is to prove $B$ has a complement and you might think to the similarities in the two approaches.

---

Consider the family $\mathcal{A}$ of all subspaces $C$ of $V$ such that $C\cap B=\{0\}$, ordered by inclusion.

The union of a chain in $\mathcal{A}$ is again a member of $\mathcal{A}$ (prove it). By Zorn's lemma, $\mathcal{A}$ has a maximal element $M$.

Suppose $B+M\ne V$ and let $v\in V$, $v\notin B+M$. Let's prove that $(M+\langle v\rangle)\cap B=\{0\}$. Suppose $a\in\mathbb{F}$, $x\in M$, and $y\in B$ with $av+x=y$, so $av=y-x\in B+M$.

If $a\ne0$, then $v=a^{-1}(y-x)\in B+M$, a contradiction. So $a=0$, hence $x=y$, so $x=y=0$.

This contradicts the maximality of $M$. Therefore $B+M=V$ and we can define $L$ to be $T$ on $B$ and $0$ on $M$.

Comment: I'm strugling to prove that $L$ defined this way is linear. Any help?

Comment: @NoGoodAtMath Since $B\cap M=\{0\}$, is there any real problem? Any vector $v\in V$ can be written *in a unique way* as $v=b+m$, with $b\in B$ and $m\in M$.

Comment: Well, I must show that $L(v_1+cv_2) = L(v_1)+cL(v_2)$. I'm stuck on showing this for $v_1\in B$, $v_2\in M$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.